# Save function response in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this script:

```
 <div id="contenedor1">
  <script>  
    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.text  = 'document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO")[0]
            .getElementsByTagName("CONTENEDOR1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);'
    $('#contenedor1').html( script );
  </script>
</div>
```

This script will print the following inside "contender".

`<script type="text/javascript">document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO")[0].getElementsByTagName("CONTENEDOR1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);</script>`

How can I print the response/content of that script inside "contender" -without printing the script to avoid an endless loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use;

```
$('#contenedor1').append( script );
```

This will append response to `contenedor1`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you mix pure javascript and jquery ?

Change:

```
$('#contenedor1#').html(script);
```

By:

```
document.getElementById('contenedor1').appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even creating a `script` element then? If all you want to do is add the node value to that element, then just do that:

```
$('#contenedor1').html(
  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO")[0].getElementsByTagName("CONTENEDOR1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue 
);
```

There is no need to go through another layer of indirection with the `script` element.